# how to push values into an array declared globally

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello all am working in codeigniter and  my model page look like below, I have declared the array globally is it possible to push  value inside the globally declared $referrals() array

```
 <?php

    Class usermodel extends CI_Model {

               $referrals = array();

               function gettreferrals($uid,$referrals)

               {
                   $this->db->select('*');
                   $this->db->from('users');
                   $this->db->where('parent_id',$uid);
                   $this->db->order_by('user_id',ASC);
                   $query = $this->db->get();
                   $result = $query->result();
                   array_push($referrals,$result);  // pushing result in to array
               }

               function getdetails($usrid)
               {

                   $this->db->select('*');
                   $this->db->from('users');
                   $this->db->where('user_id',$usrid);
                   $queryes = $this->db->get();
                   $results = $queryes->result();
                   array_push($referrals,$results); //pushing in to array
               }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No.declare this variable as class property then you can reuse it through out the class.

Comment: Have you tried making $referrals public? You should be able to push new values then by doing it like this : `$usermodel =  new CI_Model();
$usermodel->referrals[] = "value you want to push";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use $this for pointing to $refferels of current object

```
     Class usermodel extends CI_Model {

           $referrals=array();

           function gettreferrals($uid,$referrals)

           {
                  $this->db->select('*');
                  $this->db->from('users');
                  $this->db->where('parent_id',$uid);
                  $this->db->order_by('user_id',ASC);
                  $query = $this->db->get();
                  $result = $query->result();

                  array_push($this->$referrals,$result);  // pushing result in to array


           }


           function getdetails($usrid)

           {

                          $this->db->select('*');
                          $this->db->from('users');
                          $this->db->where('user_id',$usrid);
                          $queryes = $this->db->get();
                          $results = $queryes->result();
                          array_push($this->$referrals,$results); //pushing in to array

           }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a global variable. It is a property of a class. And it can be done like this:

```
array_push($this->referrals,$result);
           ^^^^^
```

When you try to access a property of the class, you need to prepend `$this->` to it.